# Trying to see if a value from one array exist in another array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, comparison

I have these two arrays like so -

```
$props = json_decode('[{"proposal":"proposal 1", "owner":"tom", "lock_time":1639440607},{"proposal":"proposal 2", "owner":"bob", "lock_time":1639455554}]', true);

$votes = json_decode('[{"vote":"approve", "vote-owner":"tom", "prop-id":1639440607},{"vote":"reject", "vote-owner":"bob", "prop-id":1639455554},{"vote":"reject", "vote-owner":"tom", "prop-id":1639440607}]', true);
```

When I loop through array one and array two I count the votes for each proposal. I would like to know when a user has voted on each proposal as well. I cant seem to get it to work as expected Here is my PHP loop -

```
$owner = 'tom';
foreach($props as $props){

    $lock_time = $props['lock_time'];
    $my_proposal = $props['proposal'];
    $owner = $props['owner'];


    $approvals=0;
    $rejects=0;
    $is_voted = '';

    foreach($votes as $votes){

        $id = $votes['prop-id'];
        $vote = $votes['vote'];
        $vote_owner = $votes['vote-owner'];

        
        if($lock_time == $id){

           if($owner == $vote_owner){
               $is_voted = 'true';
           }else{
               $is_voted = 'false';
           }

           if($vote == 'approve'){
               $approvals++;
           }elseif($vote == 'reject'){
               $rejects++;
           }
        }
     }

    echo $my_proposal.' Voted= '.$is_voted;

 }
```

I suspect because im checking inside the votes loop and displaying outside the vote loop but am unsure of the right way to do this.

Current outcome is all false, expected outcome would be Tom voted on 2 of the 3 proposals so 2 true and 1 false;

Heres a demo - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/78d28ac1c251b0d006bfda6c2722b156bfaed32f

Comment: please show current vs. expected outcome, thanks

Comment: Ok I updated the question